# Populating a drop down box with inputs from database that'd lead to another populated page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

So I volunteered to create a user form at work and thought I'd add a fun little twist and do it in HTML/CSS/PHP/mySQL rather than MS word.

Basically, this is a form I'll be using to add and delete user from my database. I've already finished the initial form, created a PHP file to save everything in my database and linked it properly.

My question is, how do I create a page with a drop down list of all Names/Last Names/IDs where the person browsing it could click "submit" and get all the information about the user?

I've been googling for hours now, but to no avail as it seems that some people have similar problems, but are missing some large puzzle piece that I need as well.

I know it sounds a bit confusing, so here's my code so that you can get a better idea:

**HTML:**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 table,
th,
td {} table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 3px;
}
input[type="text"],
textarea {
  background-color: #F8FCFF;
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  Helvetica;
}
body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
f {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  source-sans-pro;
}
bigbold {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  source-sans-pro;
}
info {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  source-sans-pro;
}
.tr-top {
  border-top: 1pt solid black;
}
.tr-left {
  border-left: 1pt solid black;
}
.td-left {
  border-left: 1pt solid black;
  width: 35%;
}
.checkboxes label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.checkboxes input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkboxes label span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#body1 {
  width: 1000px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0px auto 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
#colour {
  background: #C6DEFF;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled D
    <!--#include file="NewUser_get.php" -->
    ocument</title>
  <link href="Untitled-4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--<div id="body1">-->
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="head">

      <form action="NewUser_get.php" method="POST">
        <table style="width:1000px">
          <tr>
            <td width=90%>
              <f>Request date:</f>
              <br>
              <input type="date" name="RequestDate">
            </td>
            <td width=10%>
              <f>Requested by:</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" style="width: 166px;" name="RequestBy">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div id="colour">
          <info>
            <center>New User Info</center>
          </info>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Employee's last name:&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="LastName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>First name&nbsp;
                <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="FirstName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Middle name&nbsp;
                <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="MiddleName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Employment type&nbsp;
                <select name="EmploymentType">
                  <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
                  <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
                  <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>
                  <option value="Placement">Placement</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td width="80px">
              <f>&nbsp;Gender</f>
              <br>
              <label for="GenderMale">
                <input type="checkbox" name="GenderMale" value="Yes" /> <span>M</span>
              </label>
              <label for="GenderFemale">
                <input type="checkbox" name="GenderFemale" value="Yes" /> <span>F</span>
              </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Department&nbsp;</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="Department1">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Job title&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="JobTitle">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Manager's name&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="ManagerName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Start date&nbsp;</f>
              <br>
              <input type="date" placeholder="Click to type" name="StartDate">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Finish date&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="date" style="width: 166px;" name="FinishDate">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Full address:</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" style="width: 992px;" placeholder="Click to type, Address/ P.O. Box, City, Street, Post code" name="FullAddress">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>User Group / Profile to Use:</f>
              <input type="text" style="width: 325px;" placeholder="Click to type, e.g. same as John, Accounts" name="UserGroup">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Distribution Groups to be included:</f>
              <input type="text" style="width: 325px;" placeholder="Click to type, e.g. Staff, Internal, External" name="DistributionGroup">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Shared Drive Access:</f>
              <input type="text" style="width: 325px;" placeholder="Click to type" name="SharedDriveAccess">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Permissions on shared drives (in detail):</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" style="width: 993px;" placeholder="Click to type, e.g. Marketing drive 'read only, Technical drive 'Full Access'" name="Permissions">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div id="colour">
          <info>
            <center>Additional Info</center>
          </info>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="checkboxes">

          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td width="%50">&nbsp;
                <bigbold>List of required items (Tick the &nbsp;box next to an item):</bigbold>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp</td>
              <td class="td-left" width="%50">
                <bigbold>List of required software/drive access:</bigbold>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <info>&nbsp;Drives:</info>
              </td>
              <td>
                <info>&nbsp;Software:</info>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="iPad">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="iPad" value="Yes"> <span><f>iPad + case</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Mouse">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Mouse" value="Yes"> <span><f>Mouse</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Sales">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Sales" value="Yes"><span><f>Sales</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Salesforce">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Salesforce" value="Yes"> <span><f>Salesforce</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="iPhone">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="iPhone" value="Yes"> <span><f>iPhone + case</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Laptopb">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Laptopb" value="Yes"> <span><f>Laptop bag</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Marketing">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Marketing" value="Yes"> <span><f>Marketing</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="VPN">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="VPN" value="Yes"> <span><f>VPN</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Laptop">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Laptop" value="Yes"> <span><f>Laptop</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Dphone">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Dphone" value="Yes"> <span><f>Desk phone</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="General">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="General" value="Yes"> <span><f>General</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Terminal">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Terminal" value="Yes"> <span><f>Terminal server</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Desktop">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Desktop" value="Yes" /> <span><f>Desktop</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Printerw">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Printerw" value="Yes"> <span><f>Printer (work)</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="CAD">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="CAD" value="Yes"> <span><f>CAD</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Printerh">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Printerh" value="Yes"> <span><f>Printer (home)</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Dongle">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Dongle" value="Yes"> <span><f>Dongle</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Finance">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Finance" value="Yes"> <span><f>Finance</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Monitor">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Monitor" value="Yes"> <span><f>Monitor</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="MiFi">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Mifi" value="Yes"> <span><f>MiFi (Mobile Wifi)</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Accounts">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Accounts" value="Yes"> <span><f>Accounts</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Keyboard">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Keyboard" value="Yes"> <span><f>Keyboard</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td class="td-left"></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
          </table>
          <div id="colour">
            <center>
              <info>Miscellaneous:</info>
            </center>
          </div>
          <br>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <f>Should the predecessor's email be assigned to this user?</f>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Pemail">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Pemail" value="Yes"> <span><f>Yes</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-top">
              <td>
                <f>Is the user replacing someone else from the staff or is he/she a completely new employee?</f>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Replacement">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Replacement" value="Yes"> <span><f>Replacement</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="NewUser">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser" value="Yes"> <span><f>New user</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <textarea name="AddRequirements" style="width:1000px;" placeholder="Please continue here for any other extra requirements e.g. need of a special signature, software, hardware etc. or needed access to another user’s files and documents, or assign another user’s email profile to this user so they inherit all files and folders form the old user."></textarea>
          <!--<input type='hidden' name='articleid' id='articleid' value='<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>' /> -->
          <input type="submit">
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**PHP:**

```html
<?php

if( $_POST )
{
$conn = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassword", "mydb");

 if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  
  $RequestBy = $_POST['RequestBy'];
  $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
  $MiddleName = $_POST['MiddleName'];
  $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
  $Desktop = $_POST['Desktop'];
  $EmploymentType = $_POST['EmploymentType'];
  $GenderMale = $_POST['GenderMale'];
  $GenderFemale = $_POST['GenderFemale'];
  $Department1 = $_POST['Department1'];
  $JobTitle = $_POST['JobTitle'];
  $ManagerName = $_POST['ManagerName'];
  $FullAddress = $_POST['FullAddress'];
  $UserGroup = $_POST['UserGroup'];
  $DistributionGroup = $_POST['DistributionGroup'];
  $SharedDriveAccess = $_POST['SharedDriveAccess'];
  $Permissions = $_POST['Permissions'];
  $iPad = $_POST['iPad'];
  $Mouse = $_POST['Mouse'];
  $Sales = $_POST['Sales'];
  $Salesforce = $_POST['Salesforce'];
  $iPhone = $_POST['iPhone'];
  $Laptopb = $_POST['Laptopb'];
  $Marketing = $_POST['Marketing'];
  $VPN = $_POST['VPN'];
  $Laptop = $_POST['Laptop'];
  $Dphone = $_POST['Dphone'];
  $General = $_POST['General'];
  $Terminal = $_POST['Terminal'];
  $Printerw = $_POST['Printerw'];
  $CAD = $_POST['CAD'];
  $Printerh = $_POST['Printerh'];
  $Dongle = $_POST['Dongle'];
  $Finance = $_POST['Finance'];
  $Monitor = $_POST['Monitor'];
  $Mifi = $_POST['Mifi'];
  $Accounts = $_POST['Accounts'];
  $Keyboard = $_POST['Keyboard'];
  $Pemail = $_POST['Pemail'];
  $Replacement = $_POST['Replacement'];
  $NewUser = $_POST['NewUser'];
  $AddRequirements = $_POST['AddRequirements'];
 
    
}

  
    $sql= "
  
   INSERT INTO TestTable (RequestBy, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Desktop, EmploymentType, GenderMale, GenderFemale, Department1, JobTitle, ManagerName, FullAddress, UserGroup, DistributionGroup, SharedDriveAccess, Permissions, iPad, Mouse, Sales, Salesforce, iPhone, Laptopb, Marketing, VPN, Laptop, Dphone, General, Terminal, Printerw, CAD, Printerh, Dongle, Finance, Monitor, Mifi, Accounts, Keyboard, Pemail, Replacement, NewUser, AddRequirements) VALUES ('$RequestBy', '$FirstName', '$MiddleName', '$LastName', '$Desktop', '$EmploymentType', '$GenderMale', '$GenderFemale', '$Department1', '$JobTitle', '$ManagerName', '$FullAddress', '$UserGroup', '$DistributionGroup', '$SharedDriveAccess', '$Permissions', '$iPad', '$Mouse', '$Sales', '$Salesforce', '$iPhone', '$Laptopb', '$Marketing', '$VPN', '$Laptop', '$Dphone', '$General', '$Terminal', '$Printerw', '$CAD', '$Printerh', '$Dongle', '$Finance', '$Monitor', '$Mifi', '$Accounts', '$Keyboard', '$Pemail', '$Replacement', '$NewUser', '$AddRequirements');";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Basically I want to create another page where I could select the user's name, click some button, and then see all the information such as access to "sales" drive, gender, etc. displayed.

Ignore the lack of security measures in the code, it'll be used on a local server by very few and trustworthy people.

If somebody could just guide me on the right path, it'd be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to need a bit of AJAX to accomplish this.
At first, you need to make the `php` file containing the select box. Note, that you have to include jquery at html .

In `select_user.php`

```
<?php
//Connection to database
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'your_password', 'your_database');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

//Simple query to populate the select box
$query = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName FROM TestTable ORDER BY FirstName ASC, LastName ASC, id ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { //If there are records in database table

    echo '<select id="user" name="user">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['FirstName'].' '.$row['LastName'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

} else {
    echo '<p class="alert">There are no data to select from.</p>';
}
?>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Then you have to write some AJAX asking the server to fetch the user with the selected id (note that normally you have to be very careful with user inputs).

At the bottom of `select_user.php`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Each time that the value of select box changes then make an ajax call and bring the user details
        $('#user').on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id : id},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //Check if data is empty or make some other validations
                    var firstName = data.FirstName;
                    var lastName = data.LastName;
                    var fullAddress = data.FullAddress;
                    var permissions = data.Permissions;
                    var str = '<p>Name: '+firstName+' '+lastName+' '+fullAddress+' '+permissions+'</p>';
                    //Replace content at #results div
                    $('#results').innerHtml(str);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Finally, you have to create the file `ajax.php` which contains the query that brings back the details of the selected user.

In file `ajax.php`

```
<?php
//This is ajax.php
//Connection to database
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'your_password', 'your_database');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
//Never trust input from users
//Sanitize and validate variables
//Use prepared statemends or PDO
$query = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, FullAddress, Permissions FROM TestTable WHERE id = '$id';";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$json['id'] = $row['id'];
$json['firstName'] = $row['FirstName'];
$json['lastName'] = $row['LastName'];
$json['fullAddress'] = $row['FullAddress'];
$json['permisions'] = $row['Permissions'];
echo json_encode($json);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Alright, I will try this when I'm back home from work. Didn't expect someone to put in this much effort into the answer. :)

Ačiū.

Comment: Alright, tried to run the code, however I must've messed up somewhere. It does establish the connection to my database properly and selects all the IDs/Names/Last Names from it, but after I select one of them, nothing happens. The character count on comments is a bit too short, any other way I could post my new code?

Comment: You can make a new answer including your new code so i will be able to debug it.

Comment: What do you mean tried something new? As in a new database input? If so, yes. For whatever reason, when opening ajax.php in Dreamweaver, it tells me that there's a syntax error in the last line, so not sure if that has anything to do with it. I posted my current code as an answer below.

Comment: I mean if you had code changes that worked properly. If you want post your code to debug it (oh, i just saw it).

Answer (score 0):

This is the `select_user.php` file:

```
<?php
//Connection to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("****","****","****", "***");
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

//Simple query to populate the select box
$query = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName FROM TestTable ORDER BY FirstName ASC, LastName ASC, id ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { //If there are records in database table

    echo '<select id="user" name="user">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['FirstName'].' '.$row['LastName'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

} else {
    echo '<p class="alert">There are no data to select from.</p>';
}
?>
<div id="results">
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">


    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Each time that the value of select box changes then make an ajax call and bring the user details
        $('#user').on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: "ajax.php", //Tried changing this to domainname.com/ajax.php but that didn't change anything.
                type: "POST",
                data: {id : id},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //Check if data is empty or make some other validations
                    var firstName = data.FirstName;
                    var lastName = data.LastName;
                    var fullAddress = data.FullAddress;
                    var permissions = data.Permissions;
                    var str = '<p>Name: '+firstName+' '+lastName+' '+fullAddress+' '+permissions+'</p>';
                    //Replace content at #results div
                    $('#results').innerHtml(str);
                }
            });
        }
        }
</script>

<div id="results">
</div>
```

This is `ajax.php`:

```
<?php
//This is ajax.php
//Connection to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("******","******","*******", "*******");
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
//Never trust input from users
//Sanitize and validate variables
//Use prepared statemends or PDO
$query = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, FullAddress, Permissions FROM TestTable WHERE id = '$id';";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$json['id'] = $row['id'];
$json['firstName'] = $row['FirstName'];
$json['lastName'] = $row['LastName'];
$json['fullAddress'] = $row['FullAddress'];
$json['permisions'] = $row['Permissions'];
echo json_encode($json);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

This is the HTML.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled D
    <!--#include file="NewUser_get.php" -->
    ocument</title>
  <link href="Untitled-4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--<div id="body1">-->
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="head">

      <center>
        <img src="http://www.rwc.com/wp-content/themes/RWC_Global/assets/images/logo.png">
      </center>
      <form action="NewUser_get.php" method="POST">
        <table style="width:1000px">
          <tr>
            <td width=90%>
              <f>Request date:</f>
              <br>
              <input type="date" name="RequestDate">
            </td>
            <td width=10%>
              <f>Requested by:</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" style="width: 166px;" name="RequestBy">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div id="colour">
          <info>
            <center>New User Info</center>
          </info>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Employee's last name:&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="LastName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>First name&nbsp;
                <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="FirstName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Middle name&nbsp;
                <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="MiddleName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Employment type&nbsp;
                <select name="EmploymentType">
                  <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
                  <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
                  <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>
                  <option value="Placement">Placement</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td width="80px">
              <f>&nbsp;Gender</f>
              <br>
              <label for="GenderMale">
                <input type="checkbox" name="GenderMale" value="Yes" /> <span>M</span>
              </label>
              <label for="GenderFemale">
                <input type="checkbox" name="GenderFemale" value="Yes" /> <span>F</span>
              </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Department&nbsp;</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="Department1">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Job title&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="JobTitle">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Manager's name&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Click to type" name="ManagerName">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Start date&nbsp;</f>
              <br>
              <input type="date" placeholder="Click to type" name="StartDate">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Finish date&nbsp;</f>
              <input type="date" style="width: 166px;" name="FinishDate">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Full address:</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" style="width: 992px;" placeholder="Click to type, Address/ P.O. Box, City, Street, Post code" name="FullAddress">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>User Group / Profile to Use:</f>
              <input type="text" style="width: 325px;" placeholder="Click to type, e.g. same as John, Accounts" name="UserGroup">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Distribution Groups to be included:</f>
              <input type="text" style="width: 325px;" placeholder="Click to type, e.g. Staff, Internal, External" name="DistributionGroup">
            </td>
            <td>
              <f>Shared Drive Access:</f>
              <input type="text" style="width: 325px;" placeholder="Click to type" name="SharedDriveAccess">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <f>Permissions on shared drives (in detail):</f>
              <br>
              <input type="text" style="width: 993px;" placeholder="Click to type, e.g. Marketing drive 'read only, Technical drive 'Full Access'" name="Permissions">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <div id="colour">
          <info>
            <center>Additional Info</center>
          </info>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="checkboxes">

          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td width="%50">&nbsp;
                <bigbold>List of required items (Tick the &nbsp;box next to an item):</bigbold>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp</td>
              <td class="td-left" width="%50">
                <bigbold>List of required software/drive access:</bigbold>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <info>&nbsp;Drives:</info>
              </td>
              <td>
                <info>&nbsp;Software:</info>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="iPad">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="iPad" value="Yes"> <span><f>iPad + case</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Mouse">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Mouse" value="Yes"> <span><f>Mouse</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Sales">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Sales" value="Yes"><span><f>Sales</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Salesforce">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Salesforce" value="Yes"> <span><f>Salesforce</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="iPhone">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="iPhone" value="Yes"> <span><f>iPhone + case</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Laptopb">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Laptopb" value="Yes"> <span><f>Laptop bag</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Marketing">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Marketing" value="Yes"> <span><f>Marketing</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="VPN">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="VPN" value="Yes"> <span><f>VPN</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Laptop">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Laptop" value="Yes"> <span><f>Laptop</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Dphone">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Dphone" value="Yes"> <span><f>Desk phone</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="General">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="General" value="Yes"> <span><f>General</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Terminal">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Terminal" value="Yes"> <span><f>Terminal server</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Desktop">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Desktop" value="Yes" /> <span><f>Desktop</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Printerw">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Printerw" value="Yes"> <span><f>Printer (work)</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="CAD">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="CAD" value="Yes"> <span><f>CAD</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Printerh">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Printerh" value="Yes"> <span><f>Printer (home)</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Dongle">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Dongle" value="Yes"> <span><f>Dongle</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Finance">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Finance" value="Yes"> <span><f>Finance</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Monitor">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Monitor" value="Yes"> <span><f>Monitor</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="MiFi">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Mifi" value="Yes"> <span><f>MiFi (Mobile Wifi)</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td class="td-left">
                <label for="Accounts">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Accounts" value="Yes"> <span><f>Accounts</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="Keyboard">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Keyboard" value="Yes"> <span><f>Keyboard</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td class="td-left"></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
              </td>
          </table>
          <div id="colour">
            <center>
              <info>Miscellaneous:</info>
            </center>
          </div>
          <br>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <f>Should the predecessor's email be assigned to this user?</f>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Pemail">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Pemail" value="Yes"> <span><f>Yes</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-top">
              <td>
                <f>Is the user replacing someone else from the staff or is he/she a completely new employee?</f>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="Replacement">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Replacement" value="Yes"> <span><f>Replacement</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label for="NewUser">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser" value="Yes"> <span><f>New user</f></span>
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <textarea name="AddRequirements" style="width:1000px;" placeholder="Please continue here for any other extra requirements e.g. need of a special signature, software, hardware etc. or needed access to another user’s files and documents, or assign another user’s email profile to this user so they inherit all files and folders form the old user."></textarea>
          <!--<input type='hidden' name='articleid' id='articleid' value='<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>' /> -->
          <input type="submit">
      </form>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for the late reply, was a bit caught up in things. Thank you for all the help, it just feels like I can't do much at this point because I quite literally can't understand where the issue lies.

Comment: Do you have a <head> tag in your select_user.php file? If so, delete the filename and src from <script src=..."> and  write <script src="..."></script> in <head>

Comment: Alright, I added a <head> </head>  tag and put the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js></script> line inside of it. It's still not displaying my table. It does get the names and IDs from the database, but when I select anything nothing happens.

I'll submit another answer to show you how my select_user.php file looks like now.

Comment: I' m sure that we are close to solve it. Probably it's something trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
//Connection to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("*****************","***********","****", "******");
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

//Simple query to populate the select box
$query = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName FROM TestTable ORDER BY FirstName ASC, LastName ASC, id ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { //If there are records in database table

    echo '<select id="user" name="user">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['FirstName'].' '.$row['LastName'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

} else {
    echo '<p class="alert">There are no data to select from.</p>';
}
?>
<div id="results">
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Each time that the value of select box changes then make an ajax call and bring the user details
        $('#user').on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id : id},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //Check if data is empty or make some other validations
                    var firstName = data.FirstName;
                    var lastName = data.LastName;
                    var fullAddress = data.FullAddress;
                    var permissions = data.Permissions;
                    var str = '<p>Name: '+firstName+' '+lastName+' '+fullAddress+' '+permissions+'</p>';
                    //Replace content at #results div
                    $('#results').innerHtml(str);
                }
            });
  }
  }
</script>

<div id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: Also, add <html> and <body> tags just like any other page.

Comment: Alright, added the html and body tags as well, same result. Dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error in line 56 for some reason as well, it's the line that has the closing bracket } right before </script>. Could that be related to the issue?

I have to get back to work for an hour, you already helped a ton, so if I'm wasting your time just leave me be, I'll figure something out.

Comment: Just a couple of hints: Be sure that url: "ajax.php", points to correct path (maybe ../../ajax.php or something). Also, try to debug after var id = $(this).val(); adding alert(id); and see if this alerts and what. If that alerts make inside the success callback an alert(data) and see what's happening there. I hope these will help you. If you want something else feel free to ask.